# Airflow authentication setups fails with "AttributeError: can't set attribute"

Tags: airflow

The Airflow version 1.8 password authentication setup as described in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/security.html) fails at the step

```
user.password = 'set_the_password'
```

with error

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is due to an update of SqlAlchemy to a version >= 1.2 that introduced a backwards incompatible change.

You can fix this by explicitly installing a SqlAlchemy version <1.2.

```
pip install 'sqlalchemy<1.2'
```

Or in a requirement.txt

```
sqlalchemy<1.2
```

Comment: Airflow _does_ set a version requirement on SQLA - it is set to `>=1.1` - it's just that SQLA made a backwards incompatible change between 1.1 and 1.2. And 1.2 was released more recently than Airflow has.

Comment: True. Made a mistake when checking that, I'll edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Still, what would be the way sql alchemy recommends setting passwords?

Answer (score 23):

It's better to simply use the new method of PasswordUser `_set_password`:

```
 # Instead of user.password = 'password'
 user._set_password = 'password'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with

```
pip install 'sqlalchemy<1.2'
```

I'm using apache-airflow 1.8.2

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's curious about what the incompatible change in SQLAlchemy 1.2 (mentioned in @DanT's answer) actually **is**, it is a change in how SQLAlchemy deals with hybrid proprerties.  Beginning in 1.2, methods have to have the same name as the original hybrid, which was not required before.  The fix for Airflow is very simple.  The code in `contrib/auth/backends/password_auth.py` should change from this:

```
@password.setter
    def _set_password(self, plaintext):
        self._password = generate_password_hash(plaintext, 12)
        if PY3:
            self._password = str(self._password, 'utf-8')
```

to this:

```
@password.setter
    def password(self, plaintext):
        self._password = generate_password_hash(plaintext, 12)
        if PY3:
            self._password = str(self._password, 'utf-8')
```

See https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issues/4332/hybrid_property-gives-attributeerror for more details.