# Airflow basic auth - cannot login with created user

Tags: flask, airflow

I have similar situation as mentioned here [Airflow basic auth - cannot create user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48917131/airflow-basic-auth-cannot-create-user)

So, I create user like this:

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'new_user_name'
user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
user._set_password = 'set_the_password'.encode('utf8')
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

And user is created. Kinda.
If I exit from python shell and launch it again I can see the user doing

```
session.query(PasswordUser).all()
```

or

```
session.query(models.User).all()
```

But when I try to login I get "Incorrect login details". I checked all the logs I could grab from airflow and got nothing. Just a request one-liner.
Also, I checked postgres db I use. And table "users" is empty for some reason. Though if I delete this table, user creation fails, so I don't even understand in which place this user is saved.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the exact same thing happen...  and I just used the correct URI string like so...

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'user'
user.email = 'user@email.com'
user.password = 'password'

# the secret sauce is right here
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow")

session = settings.Session(bind=engine)
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

You can also use either PyCharm Pro or [pgadmin](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) to connect to the db directly.

Now I've just gotta solve the problem with it still not prompting me to login despite changing the config file.

Comment: Thanks... i'll try this out. 
Regarding your other problem to solve, you mean you are not able to see the airflow login page?

Comment: It corrected itself.. not sure exactly if it was me doing `airflow dbupdate` or one of another things I was trying.. But all is good in the hood now.. hope the above helps..

Answer (score 2):

So I found out that when I run airflow from console, it uses different db than when it is run at webserver. I used this https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow as the boilerplate to setup my instance in docker. So, if I insert needed script in some dag task and run it from webserver, it fills my postgres db all right and I can then login with a created user.
Why the heck different db is used in console - I still don't know, which is different question.

Comment: Could not add user through console, I was able to insert a user through a DAG task just like you. Have you been able to figure out why airflow behaves this way?

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why the user I created via `airflow users create` was unable to login (i saw it in the `ab_users` table but not `users`), so I wrapped up the answer from @Matt Camp:

```
"""Because this worked and airflow users create did not..."""
from getpass import getpass

from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser


def add_user(username: str, password: str, email: str, superuser: bool):
    user = PasswordUser(models.User())
    user.username = username
    user.email = email
    user.password = password
    user.superuser = superuser

    session = settings.Session()
    session.add(user)
    session.commit()
    session.close()


def main():
    user = input("Enter username: ")
    email = input("Enter email: ")
    password1 = getpass("Enter password: ")
    password2 = getpass("Confirm password: ")
    assert password1 == password2, "Passwords do not match"

    superuser = input("Superuser? [y/n]: ") == "y"

    print("user=%s, email=%s, superuser=%s" % (user, email, superuser))
    confirm = input("Confirm? [y/n]: ") == "y"
    if not confirm:
        print("Aborting")
        return

    add_user(user, password1, email, superuser)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```